# Getting values from a input text for each button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I get the value of which input text when a button is clicked, while having different buttons for each as well?

My first script was this to check if value is undefined or null:

```js
var inp = $('input[type=url]');
if (typeof(inp) != "undefined" && inp !== null) {
  console.log(inp.val());
}
```

```html
<input type="url" id="url1"><button id="btn1">Click me</button>
<input type="url" id="url2"><button id="btn2">Click me</button>
<input type="url" id="url3"><button id="btn3">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Dint get your question. So you want to get the value of that textbox for which the button has been pressed ?

Comment: Yes, if btn1 was clicked get input value of #url1, if btn2 so on and so forth

Comment: Thank you all, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use attribute selector starts with(^) in jquery and use prev() method to get the appropriate input values

```js
    $("[id^=btn]").click(function() {
         console.log($(this).prev().val());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="url" id="url1"><button id="btn1">Click me</button>
<input type="url" id="url2"><button id="btn2">Click me</button>
<input type="url" id="url3"><button id="btn3">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
<input type="url" id="url1"><button id="btn1" onclick="check('url1');">Click me</button>
<input type="url" id="url2"><button id="btn2"  onclick="check('url2');">Click me</button>
<input type="url" id="url3"><button id="btn3"  onclick="check('url3');">Click me</button>
```

In your js :

```
function check(id){
      if($('#'+id).val()!='' && typeof($('#'+id).val()) != "undefined" && $('#'+id).val() !== null){
    alert('checked');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code :

html :-

```
<input type="url" id="url1"><button id="btn1" onclick="fnclick(1)">Click me</button>
<input type="url" id="url2"><button id="btn2" onclick="fnclick(2)">Click me</button>
<input type="url" id="url3"><button id="btn3" onclick="fnclick(3)">Click me</button>
```

script:-

```
function fnclick(id) {
    var res = $("url"+id).val();
    if(typeof(res) != "undefined" && res !== null) {
        console.log(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
  var inp = $(this).prev().val();
  alert(inp);
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6azLaa50/)

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others

Answer (score 0):

If you need respected button try like this:`prev('input')` .If condition apply with direct  `if($(this).prev(inp).val())` its match both `null & undefined`

```js
$('button').click(function () {
var inp = $('input[type=url]');
        if($(this).prev(inp).val()) {
         console.log($(this).prev(inp).val());
        }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="url" id="url1"><button id="btn1">Click me</button>
<input type="url" id="url2"><button id="btn2">Click me</button>
<input type="url" id="url3"><button id="btn3">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You include `if condition` and then it only returns value when input consist of some `value` else false, as below,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').on('click',function(){
var a = $(this).prev().val();
if(a){
    console.log(a);
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="url" id="url1"><button id="btn1">Click me</button>
<input type="url" id="url2"><button id="btn2">Click me</button>
<input type="url" id="url3"><button id="btn3">Click me</button>
```